# Can c file read localized string in Xcode?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, localization

App is written in Objective-c, but it also needs some c files. And the c files contain some strings need to be localized. Such as:

```
sprintf("%dx%d, %d balls", w, h, ballCount);
printf("Hello");
```

Usually Objective-c can get localized string like this:

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"%dx%d, %d balls",@""), w, h, ballCount];
NSString* text2 = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello",@"");
```

`Localizable.strings`

```
"%dx%d, %d balls" = "%dx%d, %d couilles";
"Hello" = "Bonjour";
```

Can c file read localized string files like Objective-c?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. There are a number of ways to separate out localized strings. Look here for one method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403747/bests-practices-for-localized-texts-in-c-cross-platform-applications

Comment: It's all about the parsing since it's a simple text file.

Comment: @torstenvl sorry, cannot find a solution from the reference.

Comment: @Larme localized string is stored in file `Localizable.strings`, how can parse it? Can give a sample code? Thanks.

Comment: @jdleung, the link provides a clear answer for achieving what you want to do. If your question is "how can I parse an objective C localizable.strings file?" then nobody can help you unless you explain the file format and show your first attempts.